# How do I destroy my app after bootstrapping it?

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

I have the following method that we use to bootstrap "smaller angular apps" in a much larger project that is currently only somewhat converted to angularjs. As such we have fragmentations of the project that exist as separate angular apps. These are bootstrapped like such:

```
startMyAngularApp = (element) ->
    element.append("<div id='myDirective' 'my-directive' ></div>")    
    $injector = angular.bootstrap($('#myDirective'), [])
    $injector.invoke ($rootScope) ->
      $rootScope.$on 'event:closeDialog', (success) ->
        $rootScope.$destroy()
      $rootScope.$apply()

$(".myButton").on('click', () -> startMyAngularApp(this))
```

Now. The problem here is that every time myButton is clicked a new rootScope is created. The old one is still available through Batarang which leads me to believe that it is never properly disposed of. Is there any way to ensure that we clean up properly after ourselves?

So far I have tried with `element.empty()`, `angular.element(element).scope().$destroy()` and similar desperate attempts.

edit: Figured a screenshot of the scopes being created as soon through Batarang would be somewhat useful.

[image]